# Questions about Node.js. SChema and models

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Questions about Node.js. Schema, models and npm.
I am new to node.js, and am following the steps to make schema and models in mongoose documentation.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/

I am trying to output the model that I made in index.js using kittens.js, but I'm not sure if I'm doing correct.

There is error When I try to compile,

```
C:\Atom\initial\index.js:11
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection_error'));
  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Atom\initial\index.js:11:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

I have following codes in index.js.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var path = require('path');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var Kitty = require('./models/kittens.js');
    mongoose.connect("my database");

    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection_error'));

    db.once('open', function(){
       console.log("Connected!");
    });

    var db = mongoose.connection;

    var Kitty = db.model('Kitty', kittySchema);

    var silence = new Kitty({name: 'Silence'});
    console.log(silence.name);

    db.close();
```

and this is my model schema.

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var kittySchema = new Schema({
     name: String
    });

    var Kitty = mongoose.model('Kitty', kittySchema);
    module.exports = Kitty;
```

Initially, I thought this is because I didn't do install npm express and mongoose, but when I tried to install them, there is error message like this

```
[    ..............] \ fetchMetadata: verb afterAddevents.js:160ps://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: This socket is closed
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:678:19)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:729:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:333:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:319:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:246:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:656:40)
    at Object.Gauge._doRedraw (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_mo
dules\gauge\index.js:208:26)
    at Object.Gauge.hide (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules
\gauge\index.js:162:8)
    at EventEmitter.log.clearProgress (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog
\log.js:127:14)
    at EventEmitter.log.disableProgress (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npml
og\log.js:88:8)
```

When I tried to install express and mongoose in other files, this happened as well.

Any ideas help me! Thank you!

Comment: @mrogers there is `var db = mongoose.connection;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually functions are hoisted on the top so first you have to define db varialble then use it.

```
 var express = require('express');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var path = require('path');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var Kitty = require('./models/kittens.js');
    mongoose.connect("my database");
    var db = mongoose.connection;

    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection_error'));

    db.once('open', function(){
       console.log("Connected!");
    });



    var Kitty = db.model('Kitty', kittySchema);

    var silence = new Kitty({name: 'Silence'});
    console.log(silence.name);

    db.close();
```

Comment: Oh yeah, haha. I forgot db variable. I added one, thanks, but now my error says this.

Comment: I deleted     "var Kitty = db.model('Kitty', kittySchema);". It runs fine now! Thank you